# Save TextBox value to Ini File

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ini

I have had some great help from another member here already. However, I am stuck again.
I have a cfg file, which is basically the exact same as an Ini file. I can load the Sections to ListBox1 just fine and when I select a Section it displays the Key in ListBox2 and when I select a Key it displays the value of that key in TextBox1. That all works perfectly thanks to one of the members here.
Now, where I am stuck is, if I want to change the value shown in TextBox1 and save it to the cfg file.
I have tried the normal method of SaveFileDialog. But I don't want to have the option of saving a new file. I just want to change the value in the existing file without showing a Dialog. Hope this is making sense.

Here is the code:

This loads ListBox1:

```
Dim ini As New INI(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "path-to-cfg")
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ini.GetSectionNames()) 'For all sections
```

This loads ListBox2 from a selected item in listbox1:

```
Dim ini As New INI(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "path-to-cfg")
Dim section As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
For Each item In ini.GetEntryNames(section)
   ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

This displayed a value in TextBox1 from a selected item in ListBox2:

```
Dim ini As New INI(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "path-to-cfg")
Dim value As String = ListBox2.SelectedItem

TextBox1.Text = ini.GetEntryValue(ListBox1.SelectedItem, ListBox2.SelectedItem)
```

Any help is so appreciated.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Would it not suffice to remember the file name of the cfg file when it is loaded and display the save dialog only if the file does not exist, otherwise just display a confirmation to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: The file will always exist. What I am trying to do is just make changes to the key values via TextBox1 and then click Save and that will save the change made to that key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I followed the example on the following link and it worked just fine.
Thanks anyway for the help. Much appreciated.

For those interested: [Click Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1f2a9f0-9fe7-4e38-824d-bd4fdf1f9d12/vs-2013-replace-a-string-from-ini-file-buttontextbox?forum=vbgeneral)

Thanks,
Dan